# Medical dataset for annotation tool

Tags: annotations, ontology, medical

I am developing an ontology-based annotation tool for medical texts and I'm having a little trouble finding an appropriate data set.

I am using the Disease Ontology and so I need a medical data set focused on diseases and their symptoms/treatments.

The data set should preferably be natural language texts (articles, studies, etc) but dictionary-based and list-based ones could also be helpful.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you are looking for a biomedical text corpora to annotate? ie. identify the key terms. You could try pubmed abstracts - they're in the [Linked Open Data cloud](http://thedatahub.org/dataset/bio2rdf-pubmed), you could try Wikipedia for consumer level stuff, or even the NIH websites directory of open access journals would have plenty of open academic stuff to annotate.

If you haven't already - check out the [UMLS](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/) (and its side projects like [metamap](http://metamap.nlm.nih.gov/)) - its invaluable for any kind of biomedical NLP. If you're interested, I think I have a copy of mapping files between UMLS and disease ontology. ([RDF UMLS](http://link.informatics.stonybrook.edu/umls/), http://linkedlifedata.com)

Answer (score 0):

I'm biased (as I'm the co-founder), still on [tagtog.net](http://tagtog.net/-corpora) you find a bunch of [biomedical corpora](https://www.tagtog.net/-corpora). For instance, the IDP4+ corpus annotates genetic mutation mentions and their effects (some diseases too), and the V300 corpus annotates disease-causing viruses.